# What is the difference between ['pmadb'] and ['controlhost'] server configuration?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've read the phpMyAdmin 4 documentation on both things, but I just want to clarify if there is a difference.

I found an answer on configuring phpMyAdmin that says use ['pmadb'] ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506224/connection-for-controluser-as-defined-in-your-configuration-failed-phpmyadmin-xa)). I tried it, and it works; however, my config.sample.inc.php contains ['controlhost'].

Answer (score 1):

Pmadb contains the name of the database which holds the configuration storage. If you want to put this database on a host different than the main host (as defined in "host"), use controlhost for this.