# Digital Ocean droplet MySQL fails

Tags: php, mysql, digital-ocean

From time to time something goes wrong with MySQL on a server using Digital Ocean, all connections to the database on that server fail and I cant log into Phpmyadmin. I see an error... "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed".

Restarting using the following solves the issue

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

But this has happened twice now and I've no idea how to prevent it happening again.

I found this thread but no luck there...

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-connect-to-mysql-connection-for-controluser-as-defined-in-your-configuration-failed

Im running Ubuntu 14.04

Thank you

Comment: Are you running Cpanel?

Comment: No not running cpanel

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506224/connection-for-controluser-as-defined-in-your-configuration-failed-phpmyadmin-xa)