# Suddenly cannot access to database on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a warning like -->

> " Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/tokoonline/admin/login.php on line 4"

and some error when I access phpmyadmin.

I guess that it because django server that I run before it. but ijust don't know.

ps: there is no problem like this before. so there is no problem with my code.

[When I access to phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cWJp.png)

[When I access to my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXuw6.png)

so what I have to do to solve this. thanks before...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905049/php-warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to use the right database information from your config.php and admin/config.php files. Also ensure to set full database permissions. Also ensure you are successfully telneting to mysql port.