# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002) with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm building a web app that takes a file from a form and then uploads it to an MySQL database.

Each time I run the code, I receive the following error:

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002) with MySQL`

I am running the code on `localhost`

My localhost is connected to `Localhost via UNIX socket`

Some of the answers on stackexchange refer to MAMP but I'm not using that. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you show us the connection code please?

Comment: Kindly See if this question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27905049/14066311

Comment: @PrinceDorcis Thanks but I'm not using MAMP and I'm using php7