# Dropping Database in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using linux and I just finished installing xampp right now. I tried creating a database and wanted to delete it because I got it wrong. When I tried dropping the database. A mySQL error pops up and says:

> ## 1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist in engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems your config file config.inc.php does not contain following line:-

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pma__column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';`

Check more ["Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed" with phpMyAdmin in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506224/connection-for-controluser-as-defined-in-your-configuration-failed-phpmyadmin-xa/11506495#11506495)

Comment: i cant even select the database cause the error always poops up

Comment: Try adding above line in configuration file and restart it.

Comment: Or temporarily comment out the pmadb line in config.inc.php, close and restart phpMyAdmin. You should be fine dropping your db.