# Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed -- error on my xampp server can't login in to my phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have searched in internet and stackexchange nothing worked for me. That's why I have created the same question again.

1. I am using php 5.6
2. I am using Xampp

Errors: 
1. MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

2. Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
3. phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

[image: Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed]
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

[image: Under my Xampp server MySQL started]
Under my Xampp server MySQL started

Help me to login in to my phpmyadmin  and solve this problem.
Thank in advance

Comment: i have no idea im using xamp for a long time and i never saw something like that. did you try to change port?

Comment: Was this one of the things you tried... I've never had this issue so this is just for your reference to try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506224/connection-for-controluser-as-defined-in-your-configuration-failed-with-phpmya

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Nothing is working. I can't able to access or login in to my phpmyadmin. But my MySQL server is up and running.

Comment: @felixsturm yes my MySQL port number is 3308

Comment: Under your XAMPP Control Panel, is mysql started?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Updated my Question.

Comment: Is this a brand new installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126443/discussion-between-g-naga-subrahmanyam-and-timbrownlaw).