# After Login in PhpMyAdmin getting Errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting error in PhpMyAdmin

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

[image]

**It is not dublicate - see the error `using password - YES`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin ERROR: mysqli\_real\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736319/phpmyadmin-error-mysqli-real-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-p)

Comment: Your password seems wrong. It is clearly saying access denied. Means the password or username is wrong

Comment: Where can i find my password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the below steops..
1. You cannot explicitly specify that a given user should be denied access. ...
2. You cannot specify that a user has privileges to create or drop tables in a database but not to create or drop the database itself.
3. A password applies globally to an account.
4. give previledge as Yes to phpmyadmin