# Error in processing request Error code: 200 Error text: OK (rejected) It seems that the connection to server has been lost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using UniServer Zero XIV 13.x.x UniController XIV V2.3.1:

[image]

I can start and stop Apache successfully. I can confirm Apache and MySQL are up and running because I successfully mounted my website and could access it from a web browser in localhost. See this dashboard showing the green buttons (not red) revealing that both Apache and MySQL are running:

[image]

When I visit http://localhost/us_opt1/index.php to open phpMyAdmin, I always see this message:

> Error in processing request
>   Error code: 200 
>   Error text: OK (rejected) 
>   It seems that the connection to server has been lost. 
>   Please check your network connectivity and server status.

[image]

When I scroll down, I see three other error messages near the footer:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
>   Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

[image]

One thing at a time. Why is it that the connection to the server is lost? From the dashboard I always see the MySQL button green, unless I explicitly click it to stop it and turn it red:

[image]

**UPDATE 1:** The following error I fixed it by following the steps described at [phpMyAdmin ERROR: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736319/phpmyadmin-error-mysqli-real-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-p/61262488#61262488):

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpMyAdmin ERROR: mysqli\_real\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736319/phpmyadmin-error-mysqli-real-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-p)

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Yes, it does answer one of my questions, which is what I explained in my `UPDATE 1`. But it does not answer the other question that I have, which is the main question that I am asking here about this: `Error in processing request Error code: 200 Error text: OK (rejected) It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.`

Comment: Sorry about the noise here, I saw that you found that answer already and that it seemed to solve your problem, so when I flagged it as such in the system it automatically posts that comment. I didn't mean to re-post the link you'd already found.

Comment: Are there any hints in your webserver error log or the MySQL error log regarding that problem?