# Is it safe to store passwords inside the config.inc.php file for PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just have a quick question about PHPMyAdmin set up on Windows Subsytsem for Linux.

I am currently in the process of building a Shopify app and have set up the LAMP stack with PHPMyAdmin. Once inside of PHPMyAdmin, I saw an error that said it could not connect to MySQL because it did not have proper access (access denied).

In order to deal with this issue, I followed the instructions in this StackOverflow post below

[phpMyAdmin ERROR: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736319/phpmyadmin-error-mysqli-real-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-p/57469097)

The post instructed me to go create a new user in MySQL called **pma** and give that user access to all privileges followed by editing the contents of my `config.inc.php` file by adding the following code to it:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'my_password_here';
```

So everything seems to be working now but I wanted to know if this will cause any security issues for me once I put the app in production?

I am asking because, at the top of the `config.inc.php file`, it says that you should not store any passwords inside of it.

So is this something I should worry about? And if it is, how can I solve the issue of my PHPMyAdmin access being denied without creating potential security issues?

Comment: please read https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#securing

Comment: You really should reconsider whether installing phpMyAdmin in production is needed. This is a really bad idea. This tools is designed for development machines, not for production use.

Comment: @Dharman Oh ok, I thought it was used in production as well because WordPress uses it if you want to make to write SQL queries for a WordPress project.

If I am not supposed to use that in production, what else can I use as a GUI to see what is happening in my database?

Comment: @user2864740, I get that this seems like a dumb question but when I looked it up in other stack overflow posts people are freely editing the config file. So I just wanted a second opinion.

Comment: That's the thing, you should not be accessing the database neither using GUI nor CLI. Only your application should have access to the database. If you want to have GUI anyway, you can use phpMyAdmin through VPN/proxy that would allow only you to access it.

Comment: @pierre_web_dev it “seems like dumb question” because it asks the direct question opposed to the advice given directly in the config files. Consider instead: “How can a password to used to connect to phpMyAdmin in a secure manner (because the config file states that it would not be put here)”? It’s already been established one method is not good practice.

Comment: Or even “Why do people put mysql passwords in the config, even when the config file template itself says not to?”; even while an entirely different focus, this doesn’t ignore the stated information.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for the constructive criticism on how to better formulate my question. Now I understand that PHPMyAdmin is not a tool I should use in production anyway.

So I guess my next question is, would you recommend using a simple ORM to interact with my database or to just learn some simple SQL queries to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Using environment variables in PHP for sensitive configuration, such as database credentials, offers a secure approach to managing this information. By referencing environment variables in your code instead of hardcoding values directly, you can enhance security and minimize the risk of exposing sensitive data. Implementing this practice involves replacing hardcoded values in your configuration files with getenv() calls. Set these environment variables in your server environment, ensuring they're protected and accessible only to authorized processes. This approach strengthens your web server security by separating sensitive data from your codebase and reducing the likelihood of unauthorized access.
Setting Environment Variables.

**Setting environment variables varies depending on the server environment. Here's a general approach:**

```
export DB_HOST=localhost
export DB_USER=username
export DB_PASSWORD=password
export DB_NAME=database_name
```

**Using Environment Variables:**

```
    <?php

     $config = [
    'db_host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'db_user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'db_password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'db_name' => getenv('DB_NAME')
     ];

     ?>
```