# Msql: Cannot connect: invalid setting. Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

xampp phpmyadmin is not running today and giving the error on opening :

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I tried the solution available on stackoverflow by changing the config.inc.php content:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';

to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';

but this solution didn't work. I restarted the xampp, even restarted the computer but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

will solve your problem

Comment: do you use linux? 

or you can see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506495/4601426